# tf.data group_by_window() without iterating the complete dataset first

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

Having a DataSet of `example_ids` and `feature_frames` of fixed size looking like this (i.e. all frames belonging to the same `example_id` are consecutive):

```
id | feature_frame
------------------
 0 | [0, 1, 2, 3]
 0 | [4, 3, 2, 1]
 1 | [3, 1, 0, 0]
 2 | [7, 7, 1, 2]
 2 | [2, 7, 1, 2]
 2 | [4, 7, 1, 3]
```

I want to batch all consecutive frames having the same `example_id` to a single tensor, i.e.

```
id| features_batch
------------------
0 | [[0,1,2,3],[4,3,2,1]]
1 | [[3,1,0,0]]
2 | [[7,7,1,2],[2,7,1,2],[4,7,1,3]]
```

and I want to do it without having to iterate over the complete dataset first.
I thought I could use `tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer`, but it has to iterate the whole dataset, as it "doesn't know" if a frame with `example_id` `0` would come at the end of the dataset.

Then, I though, ok let's use `group_by_window` - but was surprised that it also has to iterate the complete dataset, before outputing something (use `max_len=None` in `test_reducer()` bellow to switch between the two cases).

So my question is - is there any way to achieve this (reduce all the frames with the same id, i.e. kind of the opposite of `tf.signal.frame`)?

Imagine, having a lot of long sequences, and then framing them to fixed sized windows, doing some predictions on those windows, and then ... how do we reduce the predictions for the windows into predictions for the examples. If I do it like in the code bellow, I guess at some point I'll get an OOM if the dataset is large enough, as the reducer seems to first collect all frames from the complete dataset, before starting the reduction.

```py
class FramesDS:

    def example_frames_ds(self, max_len=None):
        def gen():
            example_count = 0
            while True:
                example_id = np.random.randint(low=np.iinfo(np.int64).min,
                                               high=np.iinfo(np.int64).max, dtype='int64')
                frame_count = np.random.randint(low=2, high=10)
                print("{:4d}| {}: frame_count:{}".format(example_count, example_id, frame_count))
                example_count += 1

                max_seq_len = 8
                frames  = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=(frame_count, max_seq_len))
                example_ids = [example_id] * frame_count
                yield example_ids, frames
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,
                                            output_types=(tf.int64, tf.int32),
                                            output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None, ]), tf.TensorShape([None, None])))
        if max_len is not None:
            ds = ds.take(max_len)
        return ds


class ReducerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_reducer(self):

        max_len=100    ### SET to None - to check that no output is generated

        ds = FramesDS().example_frames_ds(max_len)

        def key_fn(example_id, frame):
            return example_id

        def init_fn(example_id):
            return example_id, tf.zeros([0,], dtype=tf.int32)

        def reduce_fn(state, rinput):
            state_eid, frames = state
            example_id, frame = rinput
            tf.assert_equal(state_eid, example_id)
            frames = tf.concat([tf.reshape(frames, (tf.shape(frames)[0],
                                                    tf.shape(frame)[-1])),
                                tf.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)], axis=0)
            return example_id, frames

        def fin_fn(example_id, frames):
            return example_id, frames

        reducer = tf.data.experimental.Reducer(init_func=init_fn,
                                               reduce_func=reduce_fn,
                                               finalize_func=fin_fn)

        ds = ds.unbatch().batch(8)
        ds = ds.unbatch()

        def window_reduce_fn(key, ds):
            ds = ds.apply(tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer(key_func=key_fn, reducer=reducer))
            return ds

        ds = ds.apply(tf.data.experimental.group_by_window(key_func=key_fn,
                                                           reduce_func=window_reduce_fn,
                                                           window_size=20))

        for example_id, frames in tqdm(ds):
            print("{}: {}".format(example_id, frames.shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [tf.data.experimental.scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/scan?version=stable):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_v2_behavior()

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 3, 2, 1], 
     [3, 1, 0, 0], 
     [7, 7, 1, 2], 
     [2, 7, 1, 2], 
     [4, 7, 1, 3]]))

empty_val = tf.zeros((0,), tf.int32)

def scan_fn(state, elem):
  if elem[0] == state[0]:
    vals = tf.concat([state[1], elem[1]], 0)
    return ((elem[0], vals), empty_val)
  else:
    return ((elem[0], elem[1]), state[1])

# Append an empty element so that scan produces the final group.
ds = ds.concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((-1, empty_val)))
ds = ds.apply(tf.data.experimental.scan((-1, empty_val), scan_fn))
ds = ds.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
for elem in ds:
  print(elem)

# Prints
# tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1], shape=(8,), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor([3 1 0 0], shape=(4,), dtype=int32) 
# tf.Tensor([7 7 1 2 2 7 1 2 4 7 1 3], shape=(12,), dtype=int32)
```